# Order of subcategories

Tags: categories

Hello,
I use the code below to list the subcategories on parent category pages. But it does not list the categories in alphabetical order. Can you change this code for me so that it can list the subcategories alphabetically?

````
/ list subcategories...
function wpse_filter_child_cats( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_category ) {
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $child_cats = (array) get_term_children( $queried_object->term_id, 'category' );

    if ( ! $query->is_admin )
        //exclude the posts in child categories
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array_merge( $child_cats ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_filter_child_cats' );```
````

Comment: I don't think you can add arguments to `get_term_children()`, so instead try using `get_terms()` and add the `parent` and `orderly` arguments to it.  Should be the same result, but now you can order them. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Then, could you please change the code above accordingly as who wrote that code for me has limited knowledge of PHP?